# awk help , find a file using a combination and then calculate sum a field inside that file with that combination

Tags: awk

I am spooling some data into a file like this

```
acb.txt 1 aa 3
gfh.txt 1 aa 3
a3g.txt 2 aa 4
tfh.txt 2 aa 4
```

The problem is

1. To fetch the file names for a particular combination
2. Open each file (we use rds tool)
3. Check the above combination in the file
4. Sum 32 field inside that file with the above combination.
5. Store the sum and the combination.

I am able to achieve it using grep and using two loops one on the combination and other on the number of file in that combination, looking for a better awk logic. I doubt grep will not be full-proof

added more info:

Using awk, how can I  store strings into a array like

```
a[1 aa 3]=acb.txt gfh.txt
a[2 aa 4]=a3g.txt tfh.txt
```

and then fetch that value from outside to open the files?

Comment: Your question is too vague. You should post your working command sequence and be more specific about the data and what the input looks like and what the output should look like.

Comment: What is a combination? It is the values in fields 2,3,4?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{a[$2, $3, $4] = a[$2, $3, $4] " " $1}' inputfile
```

That will create your array. But it doesn't do anything useful.

Otherwise, your question is still too vague. Show your `grep` and two loops and describe in more detail what it is *you're actually trying to do.*